# How to plot fdate from pandas and select date format?

Tags: pandas, date, matplotlib, indexing, format

I am dealing with pandas, matplolib and date format. I have a very simple data frame, where the date are also the index. I can plot it with matplotlib and I want to use matplotlib for its features. However, I am not able to set-up the data format.

This is my code and dataframe:

```py
date;aa;bb;cc
2017-01-01 00:00:00;   17.90;   53.00;   11.46
2017-01-01 01:00:00;    1.28;   52.00;   11.45
2017-01-01 02:00:00;   15.56;   51.00;   11.44
2017-01-01 03:00:00;    7.56;   47.27;   11.42
2017-01-01 04:00:00;   51.94;   45.49;   11.41
```

```py
DATAF = pd.read_csv(fnamed+'.dat',sep=';',index_col=0, header = 0)
plt.plot(DATAF.index,DATAF['aa'])
```

[the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwxea.png)

However, as you can see, the plot results unreadable. I have read many post with similar problem bu in different framework. As results, I am not able to handle it.

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: What is the plot result?

Comment: I have just added the figure.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will want to reduce the number of xticks to give more spacing.Example:
[image: Example:]

To show only one in two labels,

```
x = 2
plt.xticks(list(range(len(df.index)))[::x], df.index[::x], fontsize=12);
```

If you do that,

[image]

Comment: It seems a good solution. What about printing only the hour, minute and seconds? Could you also help me on that? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @diedro Use only **time** subset of it: plt.xticks(list(range(len(df.index)))[::2], df.index.time[::2], fontsize=12);